# Working of Appenders in Logging utilities (log4j) in the context of a web app

Tags: java, servlets, logging, log4j

How do appenders work in the web-app when the log results are to be printed to a single file ?

Referring to the working of the **servlets** , each request is served by a different servlet thread , and in a web application , there are numerous of requests occurring in parallel.

How is logging handled when multiple instances of the servlets want to log to the same file  ?

Is this problem handled like the critical section problem in shared resources ?

Since the operation involved is write and resource is single log file , would it not slow down the web app in order to serve the requests ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the logging framework. In log4j, `AppenderSkeleton.doAppend` method is `synchronized`, only allowing one thread to log a single log statement at a time. The good news is that unless you are logging thousands of messages per second (and if you are, you are probably doing the wrong thing or using the wrong framework), this is not a problem.

Remember that the actual writing to the file might not necessarily occur immediately as most likely there's a buffer which makes the critical section turnaround rather quick.

The scenario you mentioned is not the only case why synchronization is necessary. For example, when logging statements, there can be multiple appenders configured. Logging system has to ensure that no appenders are added/removed within a single log event to avoid situation where the same event would be logged with one appender and wouldn't with another.